# How to access Powershell through the WinX menu

Tags: windows-8, keyboard-shortcuts, windows-10, powershell

The WinX menu contains a lot of useful shortcuts which you can access by using <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> + the underlined shortcut key.

[image: WinX Menu]

In the actual WinX location (*%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\Windows\WinX\Group3*) Group3 has Powershell and Admin Powershell, but they aren't actually on the menu.

[image: WinX - Group3]

Is there a way that I can make Powershell appear on my WinX menu or is there a WinX combination like <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> that I can use to open Powershell?

Comment: BTW, don't try to modify the existing shortcuts unless you're fine with breaking with Win X menu! When I changed the startup folder of Command Prompt the entries disappeared from my Win X window D: (it was fixed when I updated to a new version of Windows.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Is there a way that I can make Powershell appear on the Win+X menu

You can replace the "Command Prompt" and "Command Prompt (Admin)" entries with "Windows PowerShell" and "Windows PowerShell (Admin)".

> "Windows PowerShell" is only an option for the Power User Menu if you've updated to Windows 8.1 or greater.

---

#### How To Switch Command Prompt & PowerShell on the Win+X Menu in Windows 8

> The Windows 8.1 update made the Power User Menu easier to access thanks to the newly added Start button, but also enabled a new option to replace the Command Prompt shortcuts on the <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> Menu with Windows PowerShell shortcuts, a more robust command line tool.
>
> 1. Open the Windows 8 "Control Panel". The Apps screen is probably the quickest way to do this on a touch interface but, ironically
>      enough, you can also get there from the Power User Menu.
>
>    Tip: If you're using a mouse and have the Desktop open, just right-click on the taskbar and then click "Properties". Skip to Step 4
>      if you do this.
> 2. In the "Control Panel" window, tap or click on "Appearance and Personalization".
>
>    Note: The "Appearance and Personalization" applet won't exist if your Control Panel view is set to Small icons or Large icons. In
>      either of those views, tap or click on "Taskbar and Navigation" and then
>      move on to Step 4.
> 3. On the "Appearance and Personalization" screen, tap or click on "Taskbar and Navigation".
> 4. Tap or click the "Navigation" tab on the "Taskbar and Navigation" window that should now be open. It's just to the right of the "Taskbar"
>      tab that you're probably on now.
> 5. In the "Corner navigation" area of this window, check the box next to "Replace Command Prompt with Windows PowerShell in the menu when I
>      right-click the lower-left corner or press Windows key+X."
>
>    [image]
> 6. Tap or click "OK" to confirm this change.
> 7. From now on, "Windows PowerShell" and "Windows PowerShell (Admin)" will be available via the Power User Menu instead of "Command Prompt" and "Command Prompt (Admin)".

Source [How To Switch Command Prompt & PowerShell on the WIN+X Menu in Windows 8](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/windows-8/fl/switch-command-prompt-powershell-windows-8.htm)

Comment: Wow. I didn't think it would be so simple.

Comment: @QMord Hehe. You're welcome ;)

Answer (score 1):

You create a shortcut in the desktop **folder**. Then you set its hidden property to true and assign it a shortcut e.g Ctrl+P

Comment: That is a way to launch powershell via hotkeys, but it is not an answer to the question that was asked.

Comment: @EBGreen that's what he said he wanted

Comment: What he asked for was a way to access Powershell via the Win + x menu.

Comment: @EBGreen "or is there a WinX combination like Windows + X + P that I can use to open Powershell?" is what he actually said.

Comment: That is correct. Your solution does not leverage the Windows + X interface at all. Which is what he asked for.

Comment: Yes but i enable him to get his job done.

Comment: So did the answer that he accepted. Which actually let him do it the way that he asked for.

Comment: who has time to remember 3-4 button hotkeys? this is by far the best answer...